# How to append div into div in summernote editor

Tags: javascript, summernote

So I have this code that inserts an iframe and a link into the document if it isn't there, and just a link if it is there. The problem is that this needs to be within a custom div so the structure looks as follows:

```
<div class="page-reference">
  <iframe src="http://www.myiframe.com/1" height="400" id="pageReferenceIframe"></iframe>
  <div class="">
    <a href="http://www.myiframe.com/1" class="page-reference-link">ref1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="page-reference-active">
    <a href="http://www.myiframe.com/2" class="page-reference-link">ref2</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.myiframe.com/3" class="page-reference-link">ref3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to achieve this using the summernote editor so an admin can make a new link and it changes the src of the iframe when a link is clicked, that part works. What doesn't work is this:

```
addReference(reference) {
    let hasReferences = /class=\"page-reference\"/.test(this.currentPage().text);
    if (hasReferences) {
        let pageReference = document.getElementsByClassName('page-reference')[0];
        pageReference.appendChild(this.createPageReferenceLink(reference));
    } else {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList = 'page-reference';
        let iframe = this.createIframe({ site: reference.site, height: 400, width: 80 });
        iframe.id = 'pageReferenceIframe';
        div.appendChild(iframe);
        let link = this.createPageReferenceLink(reference);
        link.classList = 'page-reference-active';
        div.appendChild(link);

        this.insertSummernoteNode(div);
    }
}
```

This code works on each page load once, then doesn't work until the page is loaded again. I checked that the code is getting executed subsequent times by putting a debugger on each line and they are getting triggered but the problem is `pageReference.appendChild(this.createPageReferenceLink(reference));` is not appending the created element on any attempts after the first one. I don't think I can use the summernote method `insertNode` because it doesn't seem to be able to insert at specific positions. I'm stuck on this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, make sure that there is not the computed html of what the summernote editor shows on the page or it could be confused as to which div it's supposed to append to